# Reference request: deforming a G-local system to a variation of Hodge structure

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, hodge-theory

Let $X$ be a smooth connected quasiprojective variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $G$ be a complex reductive group. Let $$\iota: G\to GL_N$$ be a representation and let $$\rho: \pi_1(X(\mathbb{C}))\to G(\mathbb{C})$$ be a homomorphism. I am looking for a reference for the following fact:

> $\rho$ is deformation-equivalent to a homomorphism $$\rho': \pi_1(X(\mathbb{C}))\to G(\mathbb{C})$$ such that the local system on $X$ associated to $\iota\circ \rho'$ underlies a polarizable complex variation of Hodge structure.

If $X$ is projective, this is due to Simpson [1, Theorem 3]; in the quasiprojective case some special cases have been written down by T. Mochizuki, e.g. if $G=GL_N$ [2, Theorem 10.5] or if $\rho$ is rigid with Zariski-dense image [2, Lemma 10.13].

I think this can probably be extracted with some difficulty from existing literature, but I'm hoping the statement has been written down explicitly somewhere.

EDIT: If it helps, I'm primarily interested in the case $G=PGL_n$.

[1] *Simpson, Carlos T.*, [**Higgs bundles and local systems**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02699491), Publ. Math., Inst. Hautes Étud. Sci. 75, 5-95 (1992). [ZBL0814.32003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0814.32003).

[2] *Mochizuki, Takuro*, [**Kobayashi-Hitchin correspondence for tame harmonic bundles and an application**](http://www.arxiv.org/abs/math/0411300), Astérisque 309. Paris: Société Mathématique de France (ISBN 978-2-85629-226-6/pbk). viii, 117 p. (2006). [ZBL1119.14001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1119.14001).

Comment: I remember that Simpson proved this for projective varieties. I do not remember seeing a quasiprojective version.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: As I remark in the question, Mochizuki has proven a quasiprojective version, just not for arbitrary $G$...

Comment: I see, I just did not read the OP carefully.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: No worries!

Comment: Apologies for an off-topic comment, but do you know if the analogous statement (say, at least for $GL_n$) is true for 'arithmetic' in place of 'underlies a polarizable VHS'?

Comment: @SashaP: This is a nice question! I think I see an argument for the analogous statement over finite fields (i.e. working in a component of the rigid generic fiber of the deformation ring of a given residual rep of the geometric fundamental group). Plausibly I see an argument over p-adic fields as well, but I need to check details...send me an email and let's discuss further? I don't yet see how to do it over finitely generated infinite fields, which is I think the most interesting case...

Comment: @SashaP: actually I think this should probably be false over infinite finitely generated fields; I have an idea for a counterexample conditional on Fontaine-Mazur, but it’s maybe too involved for an MO comment.